# writing apex DML and soql using less number of statements

Tags: apex, soql, dml

i recently started working with Force.com. I use SOQL and Apex to do DML a lot. I recently learnt a way to do something i do very frequently with very less number of lines. I would like to know if there are any such other shortcuts for frequently used SOQL, Apex, DML constructs.

Earlier i used this :

```
List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
Account acc;
accList = [SELECT Id,Comment__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :accId];
acc = accList.get(0);
acc.Comment__c = 'some text';
update acc;
```

This was replaced with :

```
update new Account(Id=accId,Comment__c='some text');
```

Comment: Does your original code even compile?  You are declaring accList as 2 different things in the same execution of code and also declare acc before needing it.  Those are just wasteful lines of code even without the DML enhancement that let you avoid using a query.

Comment: Anyways, another useful one is adding a query directly into a map:  Map<Id, Account> accMap = new Map<Id, Account>{[SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accIds]};

Comment: there was one error which i have removed.

Comment: any more DML enhancements and SOQL enhancements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common pattern that is a decently significant abbreviation is instantiating and populating a `Map<Id, SObject>` durectly from SOQL (especially if you work with triggers frequently) - for example, this:

```
Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
for (Account a : accountList) {
    accountMap.put(a.id, a);
}
```

can be shortened to this:

```
Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
```

or other collections:

```
Set<Account> accountSet = new Set<Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
```